# UITextView does not show text

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextview

I have created a `UITextView` class and I'm adding the `UITextView` on touch. The `UITextView` appears, however the set text does not appear and when I touch the `UITextView` the keyboard will appear, but when I start writing text, it does not appear.

Here is my `UITextView` class:

```
import UIKit

class TextAnnotation: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        self.text = "Text Field"
        self.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.editable = true
        self.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 200, height: 50)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and here is how I am calling this class to add the UITextView on touch:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let textCenter = touches.first!.locationInView(view)
    let textView = TextAnnotation(frame: CGRect(x: textCenter.x, y: textCenter.y, width: 200, height: 50), textContainer: NSTextContainer())

    self.view.addSubview(textView)
}
```

How do I get the set text to appear and why is not showing when I start typing

Comment: What if you set the value of textView.text outside the initializer? For example before adding it to the view?

Comment: are you sure that your initializer called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,`touchesBegan` function - is a bad place to initialise and add subview to superview, because it can be called many times.
I guess you have more than 1 instance of `textView`, and every new instance overlays previous one.

What can I suggest - is to replace `textView` initialisation and layout code to `init` or `viewDidLoad` etc. function, hide your `textView`, and on touch event - just show it.

Comment: There will be more than UITextView, so if I create it in viewDidLoad, I will not know how many to load.

Comment: Oh, got it, you need > 1 `textView`.